# input an array in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to read multiple raw text files into a SAS-dataset. Each file consists several ingredients as shown in the example files below. Each file (a dish) lists all the ingredients on one line, separated by a comma. The amount of ingredients is variable. Some example files (dishes):

Example file 1 (dish1.csv):

> Tomate, Cheese, Ham, Bread

Example file 2 (dish2.csv):

> Sugar, Apple

Example file 3 (dish3.csv):

> Milk, Sugar, Cacao

Because I have about 250 files (dishes) I created a macro program to read those files. That way I can execute this macro in another macro to read all the dishes I need. The program looks like this:

```
%readDish (dishNumber);
    data newDish;
        * Find and read the csv-file;
        infile "my_file_location/dish&dishNumber..csv" dlm=";" missover;

        * Read up to 25 ingredients;
        input ingredient1-ingredient25 : $25.;

        * Put all ingredients in an array;
        array ingredients{25} ingredient1-ingredient25;

        * Loop thrue all the ingredients and output;
        do i=1 to dim(ingredients);
            dishNumber = &dishNumber;
            ingredient = ingredients{i};
            output;
        end;
    run;
%mend;
```

Is it possible to create a SAS (macro) program that is able to read all dishes, no matter how many ingredients I have? The SAS table should look like this:

```
1 Tomate
1 Cheese
1 Ham
1 Bread
```

Comment: question is inappropriate either? what do you want to do after reading both files. Both the files can be read by using `PROC IMPORT` procedure. But it would take 2 steps to do the same.

Comment: Are they on a single line? Is each file only the one line. Please explain in detail, as is this question is unclear.

Comment: Expanded my answer to make things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems straightforward to me: read the data in vertically, then if you need it horizontal, add a transpose step afterwards.  You don't have to read in a whole line in one step - the `@@` operator tells SAS to keep the line pointer on that line, so you just read in the one.

```
data dishes;
  length _file $1024 
         ingredient $128;
  infile "c:\temp\dish*.csv" dlm=',' filename=_file lrecl=32767; *or whatever your LRECL needs to be;
  input ingredient $ @@;
  dishnumber = input(compress(scan(_file,-2,'\.'),,'kd'),12.);
  output;
run;
```

Here I use a wildcard to read them all in - you can of course us a macro with similar code if you need to, though wildcard or a concatenated filename is probably easier.  The way I get `dishnumber` might not always work depending on the filename construction, but some form of that should be usable.

To expand on why this works:  The way the datastep works in SAS is that it is a constant loop, looping over the code repeatedly until it encounters an "end condition".  End conditions are, most commonly, the `stop` keyword, and then any attempt to read from a SET or INFILE where no further read is possible (i.e., you read a 100 line SAS dataset, and it tries to read row 101 in, fails, so ends the data step).  However, other than that, it will keep doing the same code until it gets there.  It just does some cleanup at the "run" point to make sure it is not infinitely looping.

In the case of input from infiles, usually SAS reads a line, then at the RUN, it will skip forward to the next EOL (end of line, usually a carriage return and linefeed in Windows) if it's not already at one.  Sometimes that is useful - perhaps, usually.  But, in some cases you'd rather ask SAS to keep reading the same line.

In comes the `@@` operator.  `@@` says "do not advance to EOL even if you hit RUN".  (`@` says "Do not advance to EOL except when you hit RUN" - normally input itself causes SAS to read until EOL.)  Thus, when you perform the next data step iteration, the input pointer will be in the same exact place you left it - right after the previous field you read in.

This was highly useful in the 60s and 70s, when punchcards were the trendy new thing, and you would put lines of input often without regard to any line organization - in particular, if you input just one variable per row, at 8 columns per input variable, you're not wasting 72 blocks from one punchcard - so, you have input just like your ingredients: many pieces of data per row on the input, which then want to be translated into one piece of data per row in memory.  While it's not as common nowadays to store data this way, this is certainly possible - as your data exemplify.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer. My problem is not reading multiple files/dishes into my SAS-dataset but reading multiple ingredients. I expanded my answer to make this clear.

Comment: @TomDw Yes, I understand that. The above code reads any number of ingredients from any number of files.  You can of course have this operate on one file at a time as your macro does if that's helpful - just change the infile statement how you wish.  (I would suggest if it's possible doing it more like the above rather than one file at a time, unless you really need separate datasets - this will be faster and easier than combining datasets later - but that's your call.)

Comment: The @@ operator does indeed read ingrediënt per ingrediënt. But I don't see how your code reads in multiple files at once.

Comment: @TomDw The `*` wildcard in `c:\temp\dish*.csv` tells SAS to read anything that is in `c:\temp\ ` that starts with `dish` and ends with `.csv`.  There are other ways to do this, but this is the simplest assuming you have a directory with no files that you do not want to read in matching that pattern.  (It can have other files of course, but nothing that starts with `dish` and ends with `.csv` other than those files you wish to read in.)

Comment: Add RECFM=N to the INFILE statement. Without it you are limited to the default 32K line size. You could add a LRECL= option to get something bigger than 32K ,but there is still a limit. With RECFM=N you are unlimited . It should let you read a file with millions of ingredients.

Comment: @Tom That's a good point if the linesize can get over 32k/millions/whatever, but it also means it does unbuffered reads, which I'm not sure is worth it unless it's actually necessary.  I did add `lrecl` as that's clearly something that could be important, though.

Comment: @Tom I don't understand why you suggest RECFM=N.  Is it something to do with @@?

Comment: If the lines are longer than the LRECL then the INPUT will skip the ends of the lines. Using RECFM=N would allow those characters to be read. Might not happen in this case, but something I have seen with XML files that are delivered as a single line.